# Adding values from checkbox and dropdown select option

Tags: javascript, checkbox, drop-down-menu, addition

I would like to add the values from checkboxes and a dropdown menu using JavaScript (no JQuery).

My first question is how best to do this... my code is bellow.

Second question is are there disadvantages to using anonymous functions to do this?

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/Buleria28/4ysvgkz8/

HTML

```
<label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
        <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" > box 1
 </label>
 <label class="checkbox">
        <input value="50"  type="checkbox" class="sum" > box 2
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
        <input value="50"  type="checkbox" class="sum" > box 3
  </label>

    <br/><br/>

    <select id="select" name ="select">
        <option class="sum"></option>
        <option value="1" class="sum">option 1</option>
        <option value="2" class="sum">option 2</option>
        <option value="5" class="sum">option 3</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    Total: $<span id="payment-total">0</span>
```

JavaScript

```
/*To get checkbox values*/

var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
total  = document.getElementById('payment-total');

 for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var checkAdd = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + checkAdd;
    }
 }

/*To get select values*/
var dropdown= document.getElementById("select");

for(j=0; j<dropdown.options.length;j++){

    dropdown[j].onchange = function() {
       if (dropdown[i].options.checked){
       var selectAdd = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
      total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + selectAdd;
      } 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I want to point out:

- Use `addEventListener` to bing event handlers
- You can use anonymous functions but it's clearer when you declare it and give it a meaningful name
- Don't keep total sum in the HTML element. Keep it in the variable and then insert it into HTML.

I would do it like that:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.sum')
var select = document.querySelector('#select')
var total = document.querySelector('#payment-total')
var checkboxesTotal = 0
var selectTotal = 0

checkboxes.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxSelect)
})

select.addEventListener('change', onSelectChange)

function onCheckboxSelect(e) {
  var sign = e.target.checked ? 1 : -1
  checkboxesTotal += sign * parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  renderTotal()
}

function onSelectChange(e) {
  var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10)
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    selectTotal = value
    renderTotal()
  }
}

function renderTotal() {
  total.innerHTML = checkboxesTotal + selectTotal
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox" for="Checkbox1">
    <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum"> box 1
  </label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum"> box 2
  </label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum"> box 3
  </label>


<br/>
<br/>

<select id="select" name="select">
    <option class="sum"></option>
    <option value="1" class="sum">option 1</option>
    <option value="2" class="sum">option 2</option>
    <option value="5" class="sum">option 3</option>
  </select>

<br/>
<br/> Total: $<span id="payment-total">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a correction for JS regarding `select` element, I added inline comments, please check them for clarification:

```
/*To get select values*/
var dropdown = document.getElementById("select");
dropdown.onchange = function() {
  var value = parseInt(this.value); // gets the selected value from "select" and tries to convert it to int
  if(!isNaN(value)) { // if conversion is OK, i.e. it was a number
    total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) + value; // this line is copied from your previous code
  }
}
```